# Class "MSP\ReCaptcha\Model\LayoutSettings" does not exist in magento 2.4.5

Tags: magento2, recaptcha, magento2.4.5

After update magento to 2.4.5 in di:compile I'm get error

**Class "MSP\ReCaptcha\Model\LayoutSettings" does not exist**

How can i fix it or use another recaptha in magento 2.4.5

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Google reCAPTCHA module that is bundled and installed by default with Magento 2.3.x and later: https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/stores/security-google-recaptcha.html

And you should take a look at this post to know how to add MSP Recaptcha to Magento to **remove** it from your site: [Magento 2 CMS page ReCAPTCHA showing fine but Validation Failed. How can I fix this issue?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/354535/magento-2-cms-page-recaptcha-showing-fine-but-validation-failed-how-can-i-fix-t)

Comment: If you still need help, feel free to let me know, I'll help.

Answer (score 0):

> Please check this: [Magento 2.4 Add Recaptcha in Custom From](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/320488/magento-2-4-add-recaptcha-in-custom-from)

In Magento 2.4.x **MSP_ReCaptcha** does not exist. You need to reimplement your customize code.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways you can solve this, firstly, you can remove MSP_ReCaptcha from config.xml in app/etc (Not Recommended) OR secondly, you can get it from composer packagist

```
composer require msp/recaptcha
```

And then, try to run di:compile